# Refreshing HiearachicalData based on Source Updates?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, collections, hierarchical-data, arraycollection

I have an `ArrayCollection` we'll call "Items". It is essentially a flat collection of hierarchical data (each item has `Parent` and `Children` properties). I want an `AdvancedDataGrid` to display the data in hierarchical form, so essentially I could just do this and it would display fine:

```
// Note: RootItems would be an ArrayCollection that is updated so only the
// top level items are within (item.Parent == null).
var hd:HierarchicalData = new HierarchicalData(model.RootItems);
var hcv:HierarchicalCollectionView = new HierarchicalCollectionView(hd);

myDataGrid.dataProvider = hdc;
```

This works, but I want to be able to see updates in `myDataGrid` when the `Items` collection is updated (since `RootItems` won't pick up updates to any children, only the top level tasks). Is there any easy way to do this? I'm guessing I'll have to create a class that extends `HierarchicalData` and somehow alert it when `Items` changes, but that sounds like it'll be pretty slow. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: How do you want to see updated in `myDataGrid` when the collection is updated?

Comment: @Jason Towne: I'm not sure I understand your question. If some external process adds another object to `model.Items`, the grid won't refresh since `RootItems` itself will not have been changed. It will still show the original ones, but not the newly added object.

Comment: I guess `HierarchicalDataCollection` should be a `HierarchicalCollectionView`...

Comment: @Gerhard: Correct, my mistake. Editing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to solve this problem. Either you create your own implementation of `IHierarchicalData` (it doesn't have to extend `HierarchicalData` and in this particular case there won't be much code you can reuse) or you change the way you handle your data a little bit so that it fits into the standard use case:

```
[Bindable] // make it bindable so that the HierarchicalCollectionView gets notified when the object changes
class Foo // your data class
{
    // this constructor is needed to easily create the rootItems below
    public function Foo(children:ArrayCollection = null)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }

    // use an ArrayCollection which dispatches an event if one of its children changes
    public var children:ArrayCollection;

    // all your other fields
}

// Create your rootItems like this. Each object can contain a collection of children
// where each of those can contain children of its own and so forth...
var rootItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    new Foo(
        new ArrayCollection([
            new Foo(),
            new Foo(),
            new Foo(
                new ArrayCollection([
                    // ...
                ]),
            new Foo()
        ])
    ),
    new Foo(
        // ...
    ),
    // ...
]);

// Create the HierarchicalData and HierachicalCollectionView
var hd:IHierarchicalData = new HierarchicalData(rootItems);

[Bindable]
var hcv:IHierarchicalCollectionView = new HierarchicalCollectionView(hd);
```

Then you can use `hcv` as `dataProvider` in your ADG and use its methods to add and remove items. The ADG will refresh whenever you add, remove or update an item.

I suggest you do it the standard way unless that's really not possible.